# Oracle SQL: select from a set of orders only those that contain certain types

Tags: sql, oracle, count, subquery

I want to select from a set of orders only those that are marked with certain types.

Example:

Let's assume I have a table X.

```
Order   Type
123     A
123     B
123     C
234     A
234     C
345     B
456     C
456     A
567     A
567     B
```

In my case I want to select only those orders that contain both A and B:

```
Order   Type
123     A
123     B
123     C
567     A
567     B
```

My work so far:

```
WITH FIRST AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM X 
WHERE TYPE = 'A'),

SECOND AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM X 
WHERE TYPE = 'B'
)
SELECT *
FROM X 
WHERE Order IN (    SELECT DISTINCT FIRST.ID
                    FROM FIRST
                    JOIN SECOND 
                    ON FIRST.ID = SECOND.ID);
```

However, I don't like this solution. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT order_no,
       type
FROM   (
  SELECT x.*,
         COUNT( CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY order_no )
           AS num_a,
         COUNT( CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY order_no )
           AS num_b
  FROM   x
)
WHERE  num_a > 0
AND    num_b > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE x ( Order_no, Type ) AS
SELECT 123, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 234, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 234, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 345, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 567, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 567, 'B' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORDER_NO | TYPE
> -------: | :---
>      123 | A   
>      123 | B   
>      123 | C   
>      567 | A   
>      567 | B
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87f052d399dea2006ac39f4680e8030a)*

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a subquery to filter:

```
select x.*
from x
where (select count(*) from x x1 where x1.ord = x.ord and x1.type in ('A', 'B')) = 2
```

If there are duplicates in your data set, you would need `count(distinct x1.type1)` instead of `count(*)` in the subquery.

We could also use window functions:

```
select ord, type
from (
    select x.*,
        max(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ord) has_a,
        max(case when type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ord) has_b
    from x
) x
where has_a = 1 and has_b = 1
```

Comment: In first query, I think you should use the `count(distinct type)` to include the scenario if there is duplicate type for same ord

Comment: @Popeye: the sample data does not show that, but OK, I edited my answer to mention that. Thank you.

Comment: !! Comment was for OP. Your answer is completely adhering to the OP's requirement. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

A direct interpretation of the question would use `exists`:

```
select x.*
from x
where exists (select 1
              from x x2
              where x2.order = x.order and x2.type = 'A'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from x x2
              where x2.order = x.order and x2.type = 'B'
             ) ;
```

But, if you want to change the structure of the result set, this might do what you want as well:

```
select order, list_agg(type, ',') within group (order by type)
from x
group by order
having sum(case when x.type in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) = 2;
```

This returns one row per order where the order has both types.  The row also has a column with all types for the order.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness and as it's Christmas, you can also use `collect` and a [multiset condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html) for this kind of relational division problem. The following gives the order numbers whose set of item types contains both 'A' and 'B':

```
select x.order_no
from   x
group by x.order_no
having ora_mining_varchar2_nt('A','B') submultiset of cast(collect(x.type) as ora_mining_varchar2_nt)
```

I've used `ora_mining_varchar2_nt` as it's built-in, but you can use any scalar nested table type you have (though it needs to match the column, e.g. a nested table of varchar2 to match a varchar2 column).

Since the requirement here is to get all the rows, we have to either use it in a subquery, requiring two passes over the table and a join...

```
select *
from   x
where  x.order_no in
       ( select x.order_no
         from   x
         group by x.order_no
         having ora_mining_varchar2_nt('A','B') submultiset of cast(collect(x.type) as ora_mining_varchar2_nt) )
```

or else write it as an analytic:

```
select order_no, type
from   ( select x.order_no
              , x.type
              , cast(collect(x.type) over (partition by x.order_no) as ora_mining_varchar2_nt) as order_types
         from   x )
where  ora_mining_varchar2_nt('A','B') submultiset of order_types
```

However I expect building collections for every row and then testing them using a multiset condition is going to much less efficient than simply counting occurrences as in MTO's answer.